# How to keep Firefox/Thunderbird from trying to autodial in windows 10?

Tags: networking, firefox, windows-10, thunderbird

I recently updated from windows 7 to windows 10 and now Firefox and Thunderbird keep popping up the connection dialog for my VPN whenever they can't find a network (including every time my laptop comes out of sleep, before the wired connection re-establishes).

[image: VPN connection dialog]

I remember having to fix this setting years ago for windows 7, but back then it was system-wide and now it seems to be per-app (since there's one connection dialog for each app, and they refuse to use an existing internet connection as long as the dialog is open). Searching online, all the instructions I can find are for older versions of Windows and do not match what I see in Windows 10. The closest I could find is this dialog, from [Network and Sharing Center] -> [Change Adapter Settings] -> [Advanced] -> [Remote Access Preferences...]:

[image: Remote Access Preferences]

As the screenshot shows, I have unchecked "My location" from the "Enable autodial by location" section, and have also checked the "Disable autodial while I am logged on" option. It changes nothing.

How to fix this?

Update: as requested, a screenshot of my network adapters:

[image: Network Adapters]

I do not know why Windows thinks the LAN is disconnected (red "X") while simultaneously listing the network I'm connected to "LAN 2". The networking icon in the system tray confirms I have internet access (as does my ability to post this update).

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your Network Adapters dialogue showing the different adapters in the system.

Answer (score 0):

While looking for more information I found several web sites suggesting that Windows 10 has trouble distinguishing VPN from dial-up and wondered if the problem was a bad win7-win10 migration that converted the VPN into a "dial-up". Deleting and re-installing the VPN seems to have fixed the problem.

Update: ... but only temporarily. The dialog is back in full force now.